# Add using MicrosoftResearch.Infer.Maths; directive to C# Visual Studio 2010 project

Tags: c#

I already asked this question today, but I probably added too many details.
I will state it as simply as possible:
I want to add the:

```
using MicrosoftResearch.Infer.Maths;
```

directive to my C# project.
Visual Studio 2010 Professional does not recognize it and I am not able to find it in the .NET references.
Update: Update: After installing the Infer.NET 2.5 library, I was able to add the using MicrosoftResearch.Infer directive. The MicrosoftResearch.Infer NameSpace however, contains only the Graphs, Models, Transforms and Views sub NameSpaces. It does not contain the Math sub NameSpace which should contain the Method GammaLn. How do I add the Math sub NameSpace? I would very much like to see a very simple whole C# project that contains the method GammaLn and actually compiles with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Did you install the library...?

Comment: You don't need that lib! You should read comments to your previous question.

Comment: I am very sorry Andrey, but Presius Litel Snoflek is right.

Comment: Update: After installing the Infer.NET 2.5 library, I was able to add the using MicrosoftResearch.Infer directive. The MicrosoftResearch.Infer NameSpace however, contains only the Graphs, Models, Transforms and Views sub NameSpaces. It does not contain the Math sub NameSpace which should contain the Method GammaLn. How do I add the Math sub NameSpace?